# Confused about comparing a string in string array with a string

Tags: java, string

With this code I was trying to figure out if the last item in the `draftResponseArray1` is "?"
I have tried to run the code in Eclipse and I kept getting no...
But from the debugger I can clearly see the last item is "?".
I am wondering why the machine would not agree with me...

Thanks a lot!

```
String draftResponse = "Really, <3>?";
String[] draftResponseArray1 = draftResponse.split("");

int length = draftResponseArray1.length;
System.out.println(length);

if (draftResponseArray1[draftResponseArray1.length-1]=="?") {
    System.out.println("yes"+draftResponseArray1[draftResponseArray1.length-1]);
} else {
    System.out.println("no"+draftResponseArray1[draftResponseArray1.length-1]);
}
```

Comment: I'm guessing this is Java. You might want to tag it that.

Comment: Avoid comparing Strings with `==` in Java.

Comment: Thanks @Tiny!! I just realized I should use equals

Comment: Also `"?".equals(yourObjectHere)` is a better practice since it avoid NullPointerExceptions.